# Rewrite Image File Names

Tags: product-images

I am looking for a method to rewrite product images filenames with product name in it.

What I want to achieve is that a product image filename becomes the product name with some index behind. The original pictures are all named like sku, but google doesn't like that as much as the Product name.

So `654984561-15646465.jpg` should become `my-product-name.jpg`

So far I have nothing :/ Since I could not find anything about it in the search.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are several extensions that fit your need. Please find https://github.com/Vinai/nicer-image-names for example. Use `%name` in your map to get the product name.Or do a Google search to find others...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! This Extension works great.

https://github.com/Vinai/nicer-image-names